# MS access import from newly created text file (from URL)

Tags: ms-access, vba

First, some context. I have an excel spreadsheet with a module that, using a piece of javascript on the site, imports data from a text file generated by a website.

```
Set Datasheet = Worksheets("Datasheet")
...    
Set qtQtrResults = Datasheet.QueryTables _
   .Add(Connection:=URL, Destination:=Datasheet.Cells(1, 1))
   With qtQtrResults
        .WebFormatting = xlNone
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebTables = "1,2"
        .Refresh
```

The URL goes to "site.com/download.jsp?Login=abc&search=123" which, when accessed in a browser, creates a text file that downloads to the browser's default download directory.

My problem is that I need to replicate this functionality in Access, importing the data from this text file into an existing table.

Can anyone offer a solution (other than use excel)?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested the following and it worked for me in Access 2010:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub DownloadCsvFromWeb()
    Dim httpReq As Object, stm As Object

    Set stm = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    stm.Type = 2  ' adTypeText
    stm.Open

    Set httpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    httpReq.Open _
            "GET", _
            "http://www.example.com/downloads/gord/test.csv", _
            False
    httpReq.Send

    stm.WriteText httpReq.responseText
    stm.SaveToFile _
            "C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\test.csv", _
            2  ' adSaveCreateOverWrite

    stm.Close
    Set stm = Nothing
    Set httpReq = Nothing
End Sub
```

That saves the file to disk (on my desktop, in this case). The code could then go on to use `DoCmd.TransferText` to import the data into an Access table.